# Hide images based on screen size and prevent them from downloading?

Tags: html, css, srcset

I'm trying to have a particular image show on small screens and a different image show on larger screens.

I know this can be achieved with media queries but I'm concerned about both images downloading even if display is set to none.

I'm aware of srcset but concerned its not supported in IE.

I've also spent some time googling but all the posts on the subject seem to be 4 years old.

So, what is the modern method to deal with multiple images and showing/hiding them for different screen sizes, without downloading the hidden ones?

Comment: Try to use JavaScript approach

Answer (score 1):

you can define te images as background-images of DIVs. Then you use media queries with a mobile-first approach, like

```
.my_div1 {
  display: none;
  background-image: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .my_div1 {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(image1.png);
  }
}
```

that way the image will only be loaded if the screen is >= 768px.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a polyfill to support IE:
https://github.com/aFarkas/respimage